Extract reactree UML of VS Code tab to an image
i try to extract a UML generated by an vscode extension called reactree but the devs never implemented a export like to image or uml file.
The uml is also to big to capture manually because of the project size.
So is there some extension that can capture the content of the tab in vs code ide?
I searched for 1 week but nothing pops up, even with asking ai. Also tried Codesnap, doesnt work in that case.
Thanks for help.
